# Best technology for keywords to features mapping

Tags: classification

Source data = free text ("It's fresh and juicy and sweet")

Pre-defined "knowledge" =

- "fresh" -> quality of a fruit
- "juicy" -> quality of a fruit
- "sweet" -> quality of a fruit
- "sweet" -> quality of a candy

Which approach/technology would analyse the source data and assign the classes above (fruit/sweet) based on the keywords?

The goal is to later match the classified pieces of source data to user input (based on similarities).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion from Mahout IRC channel was NLTK:
http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html